# PCのchromeのマウス操作で動作確認のためピンチズームの操作を行いたい

Tags: android, iphone, google-chrome

スマホ開発で疑問があります。

Google Chrome のPC版で開発しています。
スマホ(iPhoneなど)でWebを見て動作確認をするのですが
この際に、二本の指を使ったピンチズームという動作を行い
その動作を確認したいのです。

PC版の Chrome のF12キーで開く、デベロッパーツールで
この操作をエミュレートするにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

できないなら、できない、ということで、あきらめて実機動作確認するのですが、どうも、chromeの過去バージョンではできたようなのです。

下記の2ページには、Chromeの過去バージョンのようなのですが
Shiftを押してマウスをドラッグすることで、ピンチズームの操作ができると書かれています。
しかし、現在の(最近の)chrome (バージョン: 60.0.3112.90（Official Build） （64 ビット）)では、このような操作になりません。

もう実機は不要!? Chromeのモバイルエミュレーターがとんでもなく進化していた - WPJ
https://www.webprofessional.jp/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/

Chromeデベロッパーツールでモバイルをエミュレートする | Web Tips
http://weback.net/utility/992/#contents-1

何らかの設定があるのかもしれませんが、調べきれませんでした。
やり方をご存知のかたは、教えてください。

例としての、動作確認としては、
GoogleマップをiPhoneの(アプリではなく)ブラウザで開いて
二本指で操作すると、回転がなくズームインズームアウトします。
これを、PCのブラウザ(chrome)のマウスで操作して
動かしてみたいということになります。
(PCはデスクトップなのでタッチ対応していません。)

実際に行いたいことは、自分のところのWebページの
二本指での操作を、PCで確認したいということになります。

Chromeにかぎらず、IEとかEdgeとかfirefoxでも同じことができるという情報お持ちでしたら教えていただければ、助かります。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 提示されているバージョンと環境で出来ますよ。Shiftがホールドされていないか、WEBページ側でピンチズームを無効にしているのでは？

Comment: まぢですか！！情報ありがとうございます。
何か設定が変になっているのかな。

webページ側(Googleマップページ)でピンチズームは無効になっていないのは、iPhoneからみて確認できますが、
PC版ChromeでスマホモードにしてGoogleマップページにアクセスしても、ピンチズーム操作ができないです。(当然ホイールでのズームはできるけど)

Comment: 同僚のPCで操作してもらったところ、やはりPC版chromeでのマウスによるピンチズームは不可能でした。ON/OFF切り替え設定がどこかにあるかもしれませんが標準では不可能なようです。また、ノートPCで操作してもらったところ、タッチパッドでならマルチタッチできてピンチ操作でズームしてました。私のPCは、マウスしか接続され‌​てないので、マウスで操作したいです。

Comment: 例で上げていただいているGoogleMapではできませんが、このスタックオーバフローのサイトで実施するとShiftでピンチズームできるようです。サイトの問題かもしれません。ちなみにですがShiftを押したときにマウスカーソルが○から十字矢印に変わりますか？

Comment: 十字矢印に変わります！これはそのモードになっているということなんでしょうか。
ほんとうだ。スタックオーバーフローは動作しますね！

GoogleMapはPC版Chromeのスマホエミュレーションモードでは、Shift+カーソルのピンチ操作に対応してない、ってだけなんですかね。
もしかして、サイト側に特殊な仕掛けがいるのでしょうか。

GoogleMap(拡大縮小)も、自分が作成している機能の部分(画像拡大縮小回転)も、PC版Chromeのスマホエミュレーションでは動かず、実機では動くような感じです。

Comment: GoogleMapのソースを確認すると、`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`のタグが入っているのでブラウザのピンチ系は禁止しているようです。おそらくピンチ系を自前で実装しているのかもしれません。これ以上はリーバスエンジニアリングが必要そうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
自分のところのプロダクトも、タッチ操作を自前実装していて、そこがピンチ動作に影響あるのかもしれません。
大変参考になりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで追記した部分を回答にします。

現在のバージョンのChromeのDevelopertoolでピンチインアウトの動作は確認できます。
例えばこのスタックオーバフローのサイトで実施するとShiftでピン‌​チズームできます。

ただし、例で上げていただいたGoogleMapのソースを確認すると、

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

とあり、ブラウザのピンチでのズームインアウトの制御は制御されており、自前でピンチアウトの操作を実装しているようで、実機とは違うイベント等が走り、実機と同じ検証をすることは難しいようです。

ちなみに実機が用意できるなら、USBデバック接続してデバイスの検証ができますのでこちらをおすすめします。
Android
https://blog.codecamp.jp/developertools_smartphone
iOS
http://ameblo.jp/ep-och/entry-11993131466.html